# Expand/Collapse All Button for Table with accordion rows

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created a table with accordion rows. I also have a button on the top to expand all accordions and collapse them again.

The accordions open and close individually perfectly, as well as when using the expand/collapse all button, they all expand and collapse perfectly. The problem comes in once I've used the expand/collapse all button I am unable to open individual accordions.

Only once the page is refreshed I am able to open them individually until I use the expand/collapse all button.

Any help would be appreciated.

I troubleshoot and debugged as much as possible and asked multiple people for assistance, but have been unsuccessful.

HTML:

```
<table class="fold-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="view">
            <td>Organisational Hierarchy Maintenance</td>
            <td>Test 1</td>
            <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="fold">
            <td colspan="7">
                <div class="fold-content">
                    <p>Define your strategic units and business units in a multi-level hierarchy</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="view">
            <td>Organisational Hierarchy Maintenance</td>
            <td>Test 1</td>
            <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="fold">
            <td colspan="7">
                <div class="fold-content">
                    <p>Define your processes and business </p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".fold-table tr.view").on("click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("open").next(".fold").toggleClass("open");
    });
});

function expandCollapse() {
    if ($(".fold").css('display') == 'none') {
        $("#expand-collapse").html("Collapse All");
        $(".fold").show("slow");
    } else {
        $("#expand-collapse").html("Expand All");
        $(".fold").hide("slow");
    }
}
```

**Front end preview**

[image: Front end preview]

Comment: Please add your HTML code as well

Comment: @DreamBold .. Just added it

Comment: @DreamBold i just added my css in now. Thanks for assisting me

Comment: https://codepen.io/dtaouk/pen/JjZxpjK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the live demo with arrows working http://jsfiddle.net/dreambold/q0tfp4yd/7/

Here's the working code.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".fold-table tr.view").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("open").next(".fold").toggleClass("open");
  });
});

$("#expand-collapse").on("click", function () {
  if ($(this).html() == "Expand All") {
    $(".fold-table tr.view, .fold").addClass("open");
    $(this).html("Collapse All");
  } else {
    $(".fold-table tr.view, .fold").removeClass("open");
    $(this).html("Expand All");
  }
});
```

```css
.licensing-options-page-content h1 {
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0% 0% 3% 0%;
}

.licensing-options-page-content {
  margin-top: 12%;
}

@media (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 2560px) {
  .licensing-options-page-content {
    margin-top: 8%;
  }
}

/* Main Tabs */

.main-tabs-lo {
  background-color: #f2f2f7;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 26%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 2560px) {
  .main-tabs-lo {
    font-size: 21px;
    width: 20%;
  }
}

.top-tabs-lo {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.top-tabs-lo .main-tabs-lo {
  color: #030700;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f2f2f7;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: -4px;
  border-right: 1px solid darkgray;
}

.tab-radio {
  display: none;
}

/* Tabs behaviour, hidden if not checked/clicked */
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-radio:checked + .tab-content,
.tab-radio:checked + .sub-tab-content {
  display: block;
}

.top-tabs-lo .loactive,
.label:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

/* Tabs Content */
.tab-content-lo {
  padding: 0px;
}

.tab-content-lo,
.tab-content-container-lo h4 {
  color: white;
}

/*.tab-content-container-lo {
  /*width: calc(60% - (.5em + 6px));
  min-height: 400px;
}*/

.licensing-options-content {
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

/* Table + Accordion */

.mol:after {
  content: "  g/mol";
}

.cur:before {
  content: "$";
}

.per:after {
  content: "%";
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f2f2f7;
}

.tab-content-container-lo table {
  margin: 0;
}

.tab-content-container-lo .tab-content {
  padding: 0;
}

.tab-content-container-lo td {
  border: none;
}

.tab-content-container-lo table th {
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 0.4em;
}

/*.licensing-options-page-content table td {
  background-color: #F2F2F7;
}*/

table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view td,
table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view th {
  cursor: pointer;
}

table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view td:first-child,
table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view th:first-child {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view td:first-child:before,
table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view th:first-child:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  font: 16px fontawesome;
  color: #999;
  content: "\f0d7";
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
   

 }
    table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view.open td:first-child:before,
table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view.open th:first-child:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  font: 16px fontawesome;
  color: #999;
  content: "\f0da";
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.fold-table h3 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view:nth-child(4n-1) {
  background: #e2e2e2;
}

table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view. td:first-child:before,
table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view.open th:first-child:before {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  color: #333;
}

table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold {
  display: none;
}

table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold.open {
  display: table-row;
}

.fold-content {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.fold-content h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.fold-content > table {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.fold-content > table > tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: green !important;
}

.view img {
  margin-left: 36%;
}

.lic-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 12%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<table class="fold-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="view">
      <td>Organisational Hierarchy Maintenance</td>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fold">
      <td colspan="7">
        <div class="fold-content">
          <p>Define your strategic units and business units in a multi-level hierarchy</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="view">
      <td>Organisational Hierarchy Maintenance</td>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fold">
      <td colspan="7">
        <div class="fold-content">
          <p>Define your processes and business </p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="expand-collapse">Expand All</button>
```